# Merge data frames by string existing in another string

Tags: r, regex, string, merge

I have two dataframes, `df1` has a string field containing phrases (between one and 10 phrases) separated by comma and `df2` has a string field containing one to three phrases again separated by comma. I want to merge these two only if all `df2` string phrases exists in `df1`. This is an example

```
df1<-matrix(c("aa, bb, cc, dd", "aaa, bbb, ccc, dddd", "ab, bcc, bdd", 10, 20, 30),3,2)
colnames(df1) <- c("Name", "Value")

df2<-matrix(c("aa, bb", "aaa, bbb, ccc", "cc, dd", "dddd", "bcc, bdd", 1, 2, 3, 4, 5),5,2)
colnames(df2) <- c("Name", "ID")
```

Results should be starting with this:

```
df3<-matrix(c("aa, bb", "aaa, bbb, ccc", 1, 2, 10, 20),2,3)
colnames(df3) <- c("Name", "ID", "Value")
```

Comment: Are the phrases used for merging exclusive, meaning there is at max one row in `df1` that contains all string phrases of a particular row in `df2`?

Comment: The are talking about dataframes, but the example code is about matrices. You are storing names and values in your matrices; be aware that a matrix coerces all values to one type, in this case characters. Could you make clear what you actually want to do?

Comment: We can see `"aa, bb"` matched with  `"aa, bb, cc, dd"`, would `"cc, dd"` match with `"aa, bb, cc, dd"`, too?

Comment: Sorry, I just made the matrices to illustrate the problem. My original data is read from csv files. I used dataframe but open to any better approach.

Comment: merging is not exclusive, it's n to n relationship.

Comment: both "aa, bb" and "cc, dd" should match with "aa, bb, cc, dd".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use -

```
regs <- sapply(df2[,1], function(x){paste0("\\b",x,"\\b")})
keys <- sapply(regs, function(x){grep(x, df1[,1])})
df4 <- cbind(df2,df1[keys,2])
colnames(df4) <- c("Name", "ID", "Value")
```

**Output**

```
     Name            ID  Value
[1,] "aa, bb"        "1" "10" 
[2,] "aaa, bbb, ccc" "2" "20" 
[3,] "cc, dd"        "3" "10" 
[4,] "dddd"          "4" "20" 
[5,] "bcc, bdd"      "5" "30"
```

Comment: Thanks Vivek. I got the keys. But on my original data, Keys is a list of more than 200 objects and the cbind doesn't work. for each record on df2 there are many matches on df1.

Comment: I was able to get my outcome using this approach. Thanks.